# jquery remove() removes element from view but not from page

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<div id="pic_wrapper">
    <div id="selected_picture">
        <img src="map.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and append marker divs to the pic_wrapper (see Fiddle FYI: https://jsfiddle.net/linuxoid/9w4y2cyp/)

I implemented removal of the markers by double clicking:

```
pic_wrapper.on('click', '.pin', function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('clicked')){
    // Double click
    $this.removeClass('clicked'); 
    $this.remove();
  }
  else{
    $this.addClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if ($this.hasClass('clicked')){
        // Single click
        $this.removeClass('clicked'); 
                /// do single click stuff
      }
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

So it does remove all pins which are double clicked. I can see in the console the divs '.pin' are indeed removed. But when I go through all the remaining pins and save their positions through a hidden input value, the saved data actually contains all removed pins too:

```
$('#ccm-form-submit-button').on('click', function(e){
    var dataObject = [];
    var data_left, data_top;

    $.each($('.pin'), function(index, element){
        data_left = $(element).position().left;
        data_top = $(element).position().top;
        dataObject.push({
            data_left: data_left,
            data_top: data_top
        });
    });

    var dataObjectString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
    $('#data').val(dataObjectString);
});
```

Why are they not removed by the remove()?

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally making it runnable with Stack Snippets ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the snippet doesn't load external libraries

Comment: It does, you just have them in the wrong order. jQuery has to come *before* jQuery UI. But all due respect, that's nothing like **minimal**.

Comment: there seems to be tones of uneccessary code snippets - can we just see your HTML element + function that uses .remove?

Comment: Your Fiddle and your snippet actually does not have a submit button... So your examples do not reproduce the issue. That is sad. --- Okay, try using `$('#pic_wrapper').find('.pin').each(function(index,element){` instead of `$.each($('.pin'),function(index,element){`

Comment: why not use a dblclick event?

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you very much. ... although when I open reload the results, they're moved by a few pixels

Comment: @madalinivascu, because I open a PNotify on clicking the pin and double click still fires that, which I don't want

Comment: if do not want to move red dot then comment out on **pin.css({transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'});**

Comment: @SaurinVala, if I remove that, the pin will move right after clicking the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax to ensure the `.pin` used in the `.each()` method are the ones **actually** inside the `#pic_wrapper` when the button is clicked:

```
$('#pic_wrapper').find('.pin').each(function(index,element){
```

instead of

```
$.each($('.pin'),function(index,element){
```

Comment: I was too early to jump. The pins actually double after each save. But because their positions are the same I didn't notice multiple of them. Maybe it's not the double click, maybe there's a bug in saving?

Comment: Certainly a bug in saving... Or in the load of saved pins.